# Failing to use sticky to make left image stick and right image scrolable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something similar to www.auratenewyork.com/ where the left image is fixed and the right part scrolls.What i got so far:

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky; 
  top:0;
  bottom:1000;
}
  body{
   margin:0;
    background-image:"https://i.ibb.co/2yMYTJQ/Frame-3.jpg";
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/2yMYTJQ/Frame-3.jpg" alt="Frame-3" border="-30" padding="0" width="100%">
<div>
<div class="sticky"> 
<img  src="https://i.ibb.co/Mk8rw9b/768width.png" alt="768width" border="0" style="width:40%; float:left">
</div>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/C6Wjmnz/1152width.png" alt="1152width" border="0" width="60%" height="768px">
</div>
<div style="margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;" >
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/2yMYTJQ/Frame-3.jpg" alt="Frame-3" border="0" width="100%" style="z-index:1">
</div>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/2yMYTJQ/Frame-3.jpg" alt="Frame-3" border="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. It's generally not a good idea to ask for a "fix my code" solution. In your case it would help if you limited the scope of what you need (a specific issue rather than "I need to emulate X"), and also images of your current state and the intended result.

Comment: it's working fine, what the issue?